# Passing parameters to a custom URI

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, registry, uri

I have a custom uri like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo]
@="URL:Demo Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo\DefaultIcon]
@="\"D:\\demo.bat\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\demo.bat\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\""
```

For running this from the command prompt, I use this command:

`D:\demo.bat -ping -ip 172.18.102.65`

But for running the same from browser, if I use the custom URI as `Demo:` then it is asking me to pass the parameters. I am not aware of how to pass the parameters to the custom URI if I run it form the browser.

How to pass the parameters while running this custom uri from browser? Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a custom URL, the *entire* URL is passed to the registered app/script as a single parameter.  Your app/script needs to parse the URL to extract what it needs.  For example:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Demo\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\demo.bat\" \"%1\""
```

You can format the URL any way you want, as long as it is a valid URL and begins with `demo:`, eg:

```
D:\demo.bat "demo:ping?ip=172.18.102.65"

D:\demo.bat "demo:ping=172.18.102.65"

D:\demo.bat "demo:ping%20172.18.102.65"
```

**Update:** Note, however, that this only works with Internet Explorer (and Windows Explorer, and the Windows Shell).  You need another solution for other browsers.  For instance, Firefox has its own Protocol Handler mechanisms:

[Web-based protocol handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers)

[Adding a New Protocol to Mozilla](http://www.nexgenmedia.net/docs/protocol/)

[Writing a Firefox Protocol Handler](http://mike.kaply.com/2011/01/18/writing-a-firefox-protocol-handler/)

Comment: Thanks for the information but unfortunately it is not working. When I run this URL `demo:ping?ip=172.18.102.65` in my browser, it dows not work. Even if I run this: `D:\demo.bat "demo:ping?ip=172.18.102.65"` from my command prompt, it does not work. Please advice

Comment: Define "does not work".  What browser are you using? What parameter does demo.bat actually receive? Did you try other URL formats? Did you reboot your machine after creating the Registry values?

Comment: demo.bat receives three parameters: `-ping` ,  `-ip` and  `172.18.102.65`. I am trying to make it work in FIrefox browser but it dows not work. I tried encoding the `space` with `%20` but was in vain. I restarted my system multiple time but was of no use. Please let me know how to make it work in FIrefox.

Comment: You have to re-write demo.bat to accept only 1 parameter that receives the original URL. There is no way to make a registered URL pass 3 parameters to demo.bat. [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914.aspx). If you need that, you have to use an intermediate app/script that receives the URL, splits it up, and then calls demo.bat with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: As for FireFox, it has its own mechanism for handling custom URL schemes: [Writing a Firefox Protocol Handler](http://mike.kaply.com/2011/01/18/writing-a-firefox-protocol-handler/).  The Registry approach only works with Internet Explorer (and by extension, Windows Explorer and the Windows Shell).

Comment: I have to agree that this single parameter limitation for URL handlers seems silly.  ShellExecute accepts a parameters object as well, which (if you ask me) the documentation seems to suggest is reasonable to pass an additional parameter string into the handler command.  Formatting the URL to contain the additional data isn't always useful as it's limited to MAX_PATH characters.

Comment: @JoeyCarson: `ShellExecute/Ex()` hasn't been limited to `MAX_PATH` since the days of  Win9x. In modern systems, its limit is `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH` (2080 characters). If you can design your code to skip `ShellExecute/Ex()`, then `CreateProcess()` has a max command-line limit of 32K characters, and `cmd.exe` has a max limit of 8K characters. See [What is the command line length limit?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You're absolutely correct!  It seems there's some old documentation and sample code floating around (as well as misinformed coworkers) suggesting this is not the case.  I've verified that 2080 is about the limit of the string passed to the URL handler.  I still think it seems reasonable that the additional argument string would be passed to the URL handler, even just for the sake of consistency.  Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: Is this (URI handler) still working in Windows 10? now?

Comment: @OfusJK AFAIK, yes. Microsoft is pretty good about not breaking APIs

Answer (score 10):

Not that I want to reopen such an old question but I was looking for a better answer to this all morning with no luck. The OP was lucky in that he had a batch file that was modifiable. However, I wanted to add a URI to an existing program (putty) without having to install additional files.

There were two problems as I see them, the first was the full URI including the protocol being passed as one parameter. The second is not being able to pass multiple parameters.

For the first solution of the protocol prefix, it can be solved by doing a little string manipulation. Such that the command value in the registry looks like:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "SET r=%1 & start D:\demo.bat !r:Demo:=!"
```

- /V:ON allows for the !r! replace to be delayed in execution.
- /C opens a command window, executes the specified command and closes the command window.
- SET r=%1 saves the URI, which by the time the SET is run has already
  been replaced by the actually URI string
- start starts your program or batch file in this case

The second solution now that we can manipulate strings would be to do another replace, which although I am sure there is a better way you could just chain the replaces together like so:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "SET r=%1 & SET s=!r:Demo:=! & start D:\demo.bat !s:_= !"
```

This last addition replaces underscores(_) with spaces ( ), and by making them spaces makes them become separate arguments used to call demo.bat.
Therefore, to run:

```
D:\demo.bat -ping -ip 172.18.102.65
```

Your URI would be:

```
Demo:-ping_-ip_172.18.102.65
```

Note:
I would recommend using a lowercase protocol but going with the OP's example for consistency

Comment: This is a good answer. Passing a parameter to an app to which you don't have any control is an interesting case and probably a common one as well.